# I have a fragment container view in my mainactivity, I want to navigate through fragments when click back button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation, android-fragmentactivity

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

        findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView2).popBackStack()
    }
```

this is the code I'm using for backstack navigation but the app don't exit on home fragment, and if I press back button on first fragment, the app should close.   How to do this?

This is My mainactivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene2">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image8"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/navigation_drawer"
        android:src="@drawable/three_lines"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thehelfen"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation2" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardElevation="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/person"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/my_profile"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/consultnow"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_profile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/consultnow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/consult_now"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/booklabtest"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/booklabtest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/book_lab_test"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon3"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/bookhealthpackage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookhealth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/book_health_npackages"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon4"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contact_icon"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/about_us"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contact_icon"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/contact_us"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/icon5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contact_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/contact_us"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/contact_icon"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contact_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/contact_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon5"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/faq"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/icon6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/faq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/faqs"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon6"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/tandc"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/icon7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/termsandconditions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon6"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon7"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/log_out"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/log_out"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/log_out"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon7"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon7" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

This is my motionscene file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="500">
       <KeyFrameSet>
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/cardView"
               motion:framePosition="0"
               android:translationX="-300dp"/>
           <KeyAttribute
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/cardView"
               motion:framePosition="0"
               android:translationX="0dp"/>
       </KeyFrameSet>

        <OnSwipe
            motion:targetId="@+id/imageView8"
            motion:autoCompleteMode="continuousVelocity"
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
            motion:maxAcceleration="20"
            motion:maxVelocity="20"/>



    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image8" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/image8"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/three_lines"
            motion:altSrc="@drawable/cancel_icon"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:navGraph="@navigation/navigation2" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image8" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/image8"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="300dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/three_lines"
            motion:altSrc="@drawable/cancel_icon"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="750dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="400dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:navGraph="@navigation/navigation2" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

This is my main activity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val contactus = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contact_us)
        val drawer = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image8)
        val tandc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.termsandconditions)
        val motionLayout = findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.motion_layout)

        contactus.setOnClickListener {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2, contact_us_fragment())
                commit()

                motionLayout.transitionToStart()
            }
        }
        drawer.setOnClickListener {

            motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
            motionLayout.transitionToStart()
        }
        tandc.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2, TandCFragment())
                commit()

                motionLayout.transitionToStart()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set different navigation scenarios like from about_us fragment to home fragment and so on

Comment: Navigation already hooks up to the system back button if you [follow the Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment) and use `app:defaultNavHost="true"` in your XML - you should never have to override `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: It's not working sir, the problem is, I have made a custom navigation drawer using motion layout, so, there are many other views other than fragment container view in my main activity. So,whenever I'm clicking back button on any fragment the app simply terminate. It works perfectly when I only have fragment container view in my main activity. Please guide me why it's not working with other views and how do I impliment backstack navigation.

Comment: So if you know it works in one case, then you add in some other code and it breaks, then the problem is with your other code, but you haven't included that code in your question. How are we supposed to know what to suggest?

Comment: I'm so sorry Sir,
I have updated my Question. Please go through it. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When using the Navigation Component and a `NavHostFragment`, you never, ever do a `FragmentTransaction`. Instead you should follow the guide to [navigate to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) that is in your navigation graph (your `navigation/navigation2.xml` you've set on your `NavHostFragment`.

```
contactus.setOnClickListener {
    // Use the Kotlin extension on Activity
    // to get a reference to your NavController
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView2)

    // Use the android:id associated with your contact_us_fragment
    // that needs to be in your navigation graph XML file
    navController.navigate(R.id.contact_us_fragment)

    motionLayout.transitionToStart()
}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir, This is the simplest way. I'm new to coding and android development. Slowly understanding things. Thanks for helping me.